# How to pass void return type in junit test case with 'MOCKITO_CORE when'

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have JUnit method contains the below statement and i am mocking using 'When'

`when(db.save(any(UserEntity.class)))`

above save method doesn't return anything it means its void.
could you please any one tell me how tho handle void return type in above statement.

it should be something like below, but not sure.

`when(db.save(any(UserEntity.class))).thenReturn(Void)`

Comment: Why would you need to mock this? What do you want to achieve? If you don't need to capture the method argument you can leave out this line.

Comment: I don't want to allow to save my user entity in DB whenever its gets called from test case. And return type of save method is void.

Comment: A mock doesn't save anything in the database, that is the whole purpose of a mock. If your `db` isn't a mock using `when` will be pretty much pointless as you can only use that on mocks.

Comment: okay, i will try to run it without `when` as i have already mocked db object.

Answer (score 2):

This mock recording has not value since the method returns `void` in any case.   So it is always true.
For `void` methods you don't want to mock a behavior but you may want to verify that the  method was invoked with the correct parameters.
`Mockito.verify()` may help here.
And to give more value to the verify operation, you should favor a specific parameter rather than `any`:

```
UserEntity userEntity = ...; 
verify(db).save(userEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

doNothing(), doThrow() or doAnswer() [can help](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods)

```
doNothing().when(yourObject).yourVoidMethod()
doAnswer(do-something).when(yourObject).yourVoidMethod()
```